# What does s/\G /0/g mean?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using regex in Perl. One of the things I've come across:

```
my $n = "   49 here";
$n =~ s/\G /0/g;
print $n;
```

This gives:

```
00049 here
```

I know the `s` modifier (single-line). I also understand the `g` modifier (global, which keeps track of the last match position). I know the regex replaces something with zeros but I don't understand what the `\G` AND the whitespace following it do (without the whitespace following `\G` the result is: `0  49 here`).

Comment: `\G` is called the G-Anchor construct. It means it must match where the last successful match ended.

Comment: "I know the `s` modifier (single-line)." I think you're confusing this with the substitution operator. `s` modifier: `/foo/s` Substitution operator: `s/foo/bar/`

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for clearing that up !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\G` is called the G-Anchor construct. It means it must match where the last successful match ended. Before any regex starts, `\G` (really a flag) is `true`, so it will start as true, then look for a space, find it, still true, finds the next, etc.. When it doesn't find a space, `\G` flag becomes false and stays that way (in this case).

Without it, it will look for space anywhere in the string instead of just at the beginning.

```
$ perl -E'my $n = "   49 here"; $n =~ s/\G /0/g; say $n'
00049 here

$ perl -E'my $n = "   49 here"; $n =~ s/ /0/g; say $n'
000490here
```

`/\G/g` is going to match (nothing) only 1 time at the beginning of string only because Perl won't return exactly the same match (defined as having the same starting position and same length) twice. That's why it adds a `0` there and stops in the following:

```
$ perl -E'my $n = "   49 here"; $n =~ s/\G/0/g; say $n'
0   49 here
```

In Perl, the position at which the last match ended is associated with the variable being matched (not the operator). It can observed and changed using the `pos` function. `\G` flag stays with the variable, not the regex. Since it's associated with the variable being matched, in a subsequent application of another regex, `\G` will start with the last match left off.

```
$ perl -E'my $n = "abcdefabc"; $n =~ /def/g; $n =~ s/\Gabc/ABC/; say $n'
abcdefABC
```

Comment: I don't think it's misused here - the intention appears to be to convert a space-padded number at the start of the line to a zero-padded number, so not matching after the string-initial spaces is deliberate.

Comment: Ah, I see you updated the answer as I was writing my comment :)

Comment: @psmears - Sure that could be the intent, but who knows. I know 20 other was to do it in Perl.

Comment: It's not actually a flag, `perl -E'my $n = "abcdefabc"; $n =~ s/def\Gabc/!!!/; say $n'` vs `perl -E'my $n = "abcdefabc"; pos($n)=6; $n =~ s/def\Gabc/!!!/; say $n'`

Comment: @ikegami - I think the last match position is reset after each non-global match context. Its just easier to say flag instead of at the point of hitting the `\G` construct, the current position must equal the previous position. In PHP I'm guessing initially `\G` refers to the beginning of string, but not sure.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

That's why space at start and all subsequent spaces after that are being replaced by `0` but space after `49` in unchanged.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM0wP3/1) (Uses PCRE rather than Perl, but `\G` means the same thing in that engine)

Comment: I understand but why does this:
$n =~ s/\G/0/g;
Gives this as output: 0  49 here
While this:
$n =~ s/\G /0/g;
gives this as output: 00049 here
Note that I'm using perl here (notice the whitespace in the first code)
I saw your regex demo but that still doesn't explain why the whitespace is needed :(

Comment: First `s` is for **substitute** command and `\G ` is pattern with `0` as replacement. `g` is for global.

Comment: But what does the whitespace mean ?

Comment: @ikegami: True, but the REs are largely compatible, hence the name :)

Comment: Similar, but not the same. Fixed the answer. This comment will self-destruct.